# Linearized operator: Fredholm operator? Jordan form?

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis

Suppose we are given a reaction diffusion equation
$$
u_t=u_{xx}+f(u)
$$
and search for travelling wave solutions $u(x,t)=U(x-ct)=U(\xi)$ then plugging this into the equation we get
$$
U_{\xi\xi}+cU_\xi+f(U)=0.
$$
Linearizing in some travelling wave solution $V(\xi)$ gives the linear operator
$$
L_c:=\partial_\xi^2+c\partial_\xi+f'(V),
$$
say considered as an unbounded operator in $L^2(\mathbb{R})$ with the domain $D=H^2(\mathbb{R})$.

This operator has a simple zero eigenvalue with the corresponding eigenvector $V'(\xi)$ due to translation invariance.

(1) How can we see that this is a Fredholm operator?

(2) Simple eigenvalue zero means that the algebraic and geometric multiplicity of the eigenvalue zero are both $1$ and there is an eigenfunction $\phi$ generating the eigenspace. In terms of Jordan form this means that there is a jordan block of length 1 and we have, for the adjoint eigenfunction $\psi$ with $L_c^*\psi=0$, that $\langle\phi,\psi\rangle=1$ (since the eigenfunctions of the adjoint operator are dual, right?).

Naive question: Isnt $L_c$ an infinite-dimensional operator? Does it make sense to talk about the Jordan form at all in this case?

Comment: No, there's no Jordan form for infinite dimensional operators. But why do you need it? "Simple eigenvalue" means that the corresponding eigenspace has dimension 1, that's all.

Comment: The Jordan form (resp. the fact that that eigenvalue 0 has trivial defect) was used to argue that the adjoint eigenfunction $\psi$ can be normalized such that $\langle\phi,\psi\rangle=1$.

Comment: What are you reading? Maybe it is better to post a reference.

Comment: https://www.researchgate.net/publication/240127837_Multi-Pulse_Evolution_and_Space-Time_Chaos_in_Dissipative_Systems  On page 12 top they say the normalization is possible since the operator $L_V$ has no Jordan cells at zero eigenvalue. But the operator $L_V$ there is also infinite-dimensional?

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't think I can be of any help here. Even though I recall having heard something like this at seminars, and be puzzled exactly like you. I think you'd better post this on MathOverflow, but be sure to include the reference.